# Storyboards, XIBs, and Pushes

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, push

My first app is pretty storyboard heavy (as it uses storyboard buttons to push to new view controllers).

I just added a tableviewcontroller that pushes (programmatically) to one of my storyboard view controllers.

As a result, any element that isn't added in the implementation file is missing when I do a:

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[secondViewController alloc]   
    initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil] animated:YES];
```

Instead of dragging and dropping segue arrows.

Is there a way to ensure the storyboard objects load even if the push isn't coming from the storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pushing the view controller, you could consider performing the segue programmatically. You can do so by calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue Identifier" sender:self]`. Now your segue is performed the same way as if it was from a storyboard, but with a different sender. You can of course set this sender to be anything you want or need it to be.

Comment: Awesome! How do you specify which view controller the segue is performing a push to?

Comment: For this to work, you do need a segue in your storyboard. This could be a very "generic" one, from one view controller (not just a specific view in that view controller, but from the view controller itself) to another. If that's not an option, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks Scott. I didn't see that you could tag a storyboard segue with an identifier.